# QT C++: multiple definition of functions when header file include in MainWindow.h

Tags: c++, qt

Ok I have a MainWindow class that is comprised of the usual mainwindow.h and mainwindow.cpp. If I change nothing when the project is generated by qtcreator and add elements to the ui from code or designer everything compiles and works ok. I also have a date.h file that handles dates. I have used it before in other programs as well and it works correctly. BUT. As soon as I try to include the date.h header in mainwindow.h, every single function inside the date.h file has a multiple definition warning. The date.h file looks like this:

```
#ifndef DATE_H
#define DATE_H

#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

namespace friday
{
    const float average_days_in_month = 30.42;

    // Returns true if date is in the gregorian calendar.
    bool check_date(const int &in_day, const int &in_month, const int &in_year);

    // Returns true if year is leap.
    bool is_leap(const int &in_year);

    enum {
        january = 1,
        february,
        march,
        april,
        may,
        june,
        july,
        august,
        september,
        october,
        november,
        december
    };

    class invalid_date {
    public:
        const char* what() const noexcept { return "Invalid date"; }
    };

    class Date
    {

        int day;
        int month;
        int year;


        // Leap year flag.
        bool ly;
    public:

        Date(const int &in_day, const int &in_month,
             const int &in_year) throw(invalid_date

        int get_day() const { return day; }
        int get_month() const { return month; }
        int get_year() const { return year; }
        std::string get_date_string(const std::string &format) const;

        void set_day(const int &in_day) throw(invalid_date);
        void set_month(const int &in_month) throw(invalid_date);
        void set_year(const int &in_year) throw(invalid_date);

    };

    Date::Date(const int &in_day, const int &in_month,
         const int &in_year) throw(invalid_date)
    {
         // Check date and throw exception if needed
    }

    bool check_date(const int &in_day, const int &in_month, const int        &in_year)
    {
    if (in_year < 1582)
        return false;
    if (in_year == 1582 && in_month < october)
        return false;
    if (in_month < 1 || in_month > 12)
        return false;

    switch (in_month)
    {

    case january:
    case march:
    case may:
    case july:
    case august:
    case october:
    case december:
        if (in_day < 1 || in_day > 31)
            return false;
        break;


    case april:
    case june:
    case september:
    case november:
        if (in_day < 1 || in_day > 30)
            return false;
        break;


    case february:
        if (is_leap(in_year))
        {
            if (in_day < 1 || in_day > 29)
                return false;
        }
        else
        {
            if (in_day < 1 || in_day > 28)
                return false;
        }
        break;


    }

    return true;

}


bool is_leap(const int &in_year)
{
    if (in_year % 4 != 0)
        return false;
    else if (in_year % 100 != 0)
        return true;
    else if (in_year % 400 != 0)
        return false;

    return true;
}

} // namespace friday
#endif
```

How do I solve this?

Edit: The date.h file has both definitions and declarations of the functions. So no date.cpp file exists. If I include date.h in main.cpp the program compiles normally

Comment: This error probably is caused by `date.h` content that you didn't show. You should provide [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also include guards must be reasonably unique so they won't collide with third-party code, that is at least contain company name/developer id, project and module name, for example `HEADER_DIMOS_MY_PROJECT_MY_APP_DATE`.

Comment: I'll put the code in

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/73378/

Comment: You didn't show actually error text either. Maybe you are actually getting "multiple definitions" error?

Comment: That is what I'm getting but the file is only included once, and if I include it in main.cpp the program compiles fine. I need to use dates in mainwindow.h so including it in main.cpp doesn't help

Comment: "multiple declarations" and "multiple definitions" are completely different errors. You are getting "multiple definitions" because you don't mark function definitions with `inline` keyword and include `date.h` into `main.cpp` and `mainwindow.cpp` therefore making both of them contain function definitions.

Comment: Maybe you copied instead of moved these functions and originals get pulled in by some other include of mainwindow.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain this properly. If I inlcude this file in main.cpp and not in mainwindow.h everything compiles. As soon as I include it in mainwindow.h nothing compiles, regardless of inclusion in main.cpp. I tried that. Also tried the inline keyword nothing changes. Any file I have tried including in mainwindow.h gives multiple definition warnings, except standard ones like <list>. Yet, when used in other programs even with multiple inclusions they work just fine.

Comment: It does not matter whether you include this file directly in `main.cpp` or indirectly through including it into `mainwindow.h` (which is probably getting included in `main.cpp`). Also there is a missing `);` after `throw(invalid_date` in `Date` constructor declaration, though this may be just a copypasing typo.

Comment: Ok. I don't if this is known widely and I missed it. I just split the date.h file into date.h and date.cpp instead of just one .h file  and now, it can be included in mainwindow.h with no problem. I have no idea why but apparently qt cannot handle whole .h files apparently.

Comment: If that was true then files like vector and list from the STL library also would not work. Which is the exact error you got? The mainwindow header probably gets included more than once and main.cpp is not included anywhere.

Comment: for example, i have void set_day(); declared & defined in date.h which is only included in mainwindow. If I have a single file that is date.h which contains both declaration and definition, I get this: /storage/dimos/projects/untitled1/date.h:474: error: multiple definition of `datecpp::date::set_day(int const&)' . If I then split the file into date.h and date.cpp and then date.h is again included only in mainwindow.h, the program works normally and I can use the functions and everything from the date.h file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the implementation of `Date::Date` directly into the class, so like you did for `get_day()`:

```
class Date
{
...
 Date(const int &in_day, const int &in_month,
   const int &in_year) throw(invalid_date) {
     // Check date and throw exception if needed
 }
... 
}
```

In the forward definitions defined before the `enum`, put `inline` in front of functions `check_date` and `is_leap` as already suggested by user [VTT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7860670/vtt).

Also add `inline` to the actual function implementations of `check_date` and `add_leap` which occur after your class definition in the file.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that. But as I stated in the comments, splitting the file from a single  .h file to a .h and a .cpp file worked without any further modifications.

Comment: It's actually a bit nicer to have the implementation in the CPP file. Because then the header file does not have to change if you change the implementation of a function. If the header file changes, all the units referencing it or indirectly including it will be recompiled (takes longer).

But sometimes you have no other option, for instance if you use templates.

Comment: but why doesn't qt like it when it isn't in two files? That should be supported by default shouldn't it? Am I missing something?

Comment: It works with one header file if you perform the steps above. I tried it myself btw.

Comment: Because each source file that includes the header will produce the same output for certain functions in your header. I say certain because the compiler does not complain about methods completely defined within the class, like for instance `get_day`.

So move the offending functions/methods to a CPP file, `inline` them or fully put them in the class definition like `get_day` (these will also `inline`).
Note that `inline` still produces a copy of the function, but an unique one so you don't get errors anymore.